# Differentiate form actions in GCDWebServer?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, forms, gcdwebserver

I am using two forms on an HTML page hosted via GCDWebServer. I have the first form setup like this...

```
<form name=\"vendorInput\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\">
<input type=submit value='Add Vendor' action=\"/\">
```

and the second form setup like this...

```
<form name=\"vendorInput\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\">
<input type=submit value='Add Item' action=\"/\">
```

I can't find any documentation that provides support for this; and any action string I type other than `/` causes the HTML request to break. **Is there a way to parse different actions for form submit buttons in GCDWebServer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have the action be a different path for each form and then implement a GCDWebServer handler for each path:

```
[webServer addHandlerForMethod:@"POST"
                          path:@"/path1"
                  requestClass:[GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest class]
                  processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {

  // Do something with form data i.e. [[(GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest*)request arguments]
  return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithHTML:@"<html><body>OK</body></html>"];

}];

[webServer addHandlerForMethod:@"POST"
                          path:@"/path2"
                  requestClass:[GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest class]
                  processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {

  // Do something with form data i.e. [[(GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest*)request arguments]
  return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithHTML:@"<html><body>OK</body></html>"];

}];
```

See https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#advanced-example-2-implementing-forms for an example.